# Add children of current page to an existing menu

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a menu that displays the first level of child pages of a top level page.  I now need to add a feature.  Now, if a user navigates to one of these child pages, I want the child pages of the new page to also be included in the menu.

```
For example, the menu would look like this if you were on the top level page:
<ul>
  <li>Item one</li>
  <li>Item two</li>
  <li>Item three</li>
  <li>Item four</li>
</ul>
If you navigate to one of those pages, say Item two, the menu should now look like this:
<ul>
  <li>Item one</li>
  <li>Item two
    <ul>
      <li>Child Item one</li>
      <li>Child Item two</li>
      <li>Child Item three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item three</li>
  <li>Item four</li>
</ul>

And ideally, if you selected one of those child pages, say for example Child Item two:
<ul>
  <li>Item one</li>
  <li>Item two
    <ul>
      <li>Child Item one</li>
      <li>Child Item two
        <ul>
          <li>Child of Child Item two</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>Child Item three</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Item three</li>
  <li>Item four</li>
</ul>
```

Stack overflow made me format my list as code.  The built in bullet point system wouldn't let me make bullet points deep enough.

Does anyone know how to do this in wordpress?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201010/creating_a_hierarchical_submenu_in_wordpress/

That page links to another page with a different way to do it: http://wordpress.mfields.org/2010/selective-page-hierarchy-for-wp_list_pages/

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are asking for this (taken from the [WP documentation here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_pages)):

```
 <?php
  $output = wp_list_pages('echo=0&depth=1&title_li=<h2>Top Level Pages </h2>' );
  if (is_page( )) {
      $page = $post->ID;
      if ($post->post_parent) {
          $page = $post->post_parent;
      }
      $children=wp_list_pages( 'echo=0&child_of=' . $page . '&title_li=' );
      if ($children) {
           $output = wp_list_pages ('echo=0&child_of=' . $page . '&title_li=<h2>Child Pages</h2>');
      }
   }
  echo $output;
 ?>
```

Comment: No, that does not do what I want.  I already looked at that.  I want to always show the first layer of children of the parent top level page, as well as the children of the current page.

I guess what I really want is to feel two different sets of pages to we_list_pages at the same time.